# I got formatting type error but I don't know why this happen

Tags: python, formatting, typeerror

```
#35
name1 = "eric"
age1 = 10
name2 = "jay"
age2 = 13
print('name:',name1,'age:','%d','\n'+'name:',name2,'age:','%d' % (age1,age2))
```

I got an error which is this:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

May I ask you why this error happen?

Comment: What is `'%d' % (age1,age2)` supposed to do?

Comment: `print('name:',name1,'age:','%d' % (age1,),'\n'+'name:',name2,'age:','%d' % (age2,))`

Answer (score 0):

You have passed several different string t the `print` method, they aren't one string, so the final one is incorrect : one placeholder for two values

```
'%d' % (age1,age2)
```

---

Either use one string and a placeholder for each value

```
print('name:%s  age:%d\nname:%s age:%d' % (name1, age1, name2, age2))
```

Or pass all of them as parameters of `print` (note that is puts a space between each)

```
print('name:', name1, 'age:', age1, '\n' + 'name:', name2, 'age:', age2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use f-strings which makes easier to use such as:

```py
print(f'name: {name1}  age: %d, \n name: {name2} age: %d ' % (age1, age2))
```